# Spring boot application which method will be called with no path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying a simple spring boot application. Here is my code. So when I run it is calling `sayHello()` why?

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping()
    public String sayHello2(){
        return "Hello2";
    }
    @RequestMapping(produces = { "text/html" })
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends from where you are calling the api. When you call from browser where default format is text/html hence it calls sayHello. Try calling using `curl`, it will call sayHello2

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your request header. If the request header has **Accept** `text/html` (usually from browsers), the corresponding request is executed. As @pvpkiran pointed out, try `curl` or alter the Accept header to see differences.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not providing the URL pattern both the method is sharing same
>   mapping as you have not mentioned over there i.e. "/".

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String sayHello2(){
        return "Hello2";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello",produces = { "text/html" })
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

now when u enter **/** it will execute **sayHello2()**,and when URL pattern is **/hello** it will execute **sayHello()**.